Qiskit register custom gate with non fixed pulse sequence
I want to register a custom gate in Qiskit. I use Qiskit SDK v.1.2.0 which is currently (by time of writing) the latest version.
I have a problem with the registration of my custom gate because my pulse sequence is generated by a function that is not executable with qiskit.cirquit.parameter.
I have generated a minimal example of my problem with two functions for my pulse sequence. These are example pulse sequences for simplicity but they describe my problem pretty accurately and I don't need any suggestions on how I can change this functions in order to be executable with parameter.
I need a way to register my gate in a way that the passmanager can 'optimize' the Quantum Circuit with my gate in it but the function for generating the pulse sequence only gets called if the gate is executed with concrete values (for example in a VQE). Therefore my Quantum Circuit must be dependent on my parameter but only executable with values inserted for my parameters.
Here is my Code with both of my functions. The function puls_builder_doesnt_work produces the error and if the function puls_builder_works is used at registration of my custom_gate it works as it should. If the custom_gate is registered without a pulse sequence neither of those two functions gets called so there is no error message.
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, Gate
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import GenericBackendV2
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, pulse
from qiskit.pulse.library import Gaussian
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit.transpiler import InstructionProperties

backend = GenericBackendV2(num_qubits=2, calibrate_instructions=True)

parameters = [Parameter(f'θ{i+1}') for i in range(3)]

custom_gate = Gate('custom_gate', 1, [parameters[0], parameters[1],parameters[2]])

circ = QuantumCircuit(1)
circ.append(custom_gate, [0])

def puls_builder_doesnt_work(a,b,c):
    with pulse.build(backend, name='custom') as my_schedule:
        for i in range(a):
            pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=64, amp=b, sigma=c), pulse.drive_channel(0))
    return my_schedule

def puls_builder_works(a,b,c):
    with pulse.build(backend, name='custom') as my_schedule:
        #for i in range(a):
        pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=a, amp=b, sigma=c), pulse.drive_channel(0))
    return my_schedule

backend.target.add_instruction(custom_gate, {(0,): InstructionProperties(calibration=puls_builder_doesnt_work(parameters[0],parameters[1],parameters[2]))})
#backend.target.add_instruction(custom_gate)

passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)
circ2 = passmanager.run(circ)

circ2.draw('mpl', idle_wires=False)

Although probably not that helpful, here is the error message I get:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 30
     27         pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=a, amp=b, sigma=c), pulse.drive_channel(0))
     28     return my_schedule
---> 30 backend.target.add_instruction(custom_gate, {(0,): InstructionProperties(calibration=puls_builder_doesnt_work(parameters[0],parameters[1],parameters[2]))})
     32 passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)
     33 circ2 = passmanager.run(circ)

Cell In[6], line 20
     18 def puls_builder_doesnt_work(a,b,c):
     19     with pulse.build(backend, name='custom') as my_schedule:
---> 20         for i in range(a):
     21             pulse.play(Gaussian(duration=64, amp=b, sigma=c), pulse.drive_channel(0))
     22     return my_schedule

TypeError: 'Parameter' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I have tried several things but was not successful.
I can register the gate without any pulse sequence (commented line backend.target.add_instruction(custom_gate)) but then I don't know how I can add the pulse sequence at execution.
I had the idea of my pulse_builder to create a qiskit.cirquit.Instruction but I am not sure if that would even do what I want and if it does, how I could create such an Instruction.
